# I want to remove '\' character from jmy URL using Regular expression extractor in jmeter

Tags: regex, url, expression, jmeter

Hi I'm using Regular expression Extractor to extract a URL from my json response, 
but the issue is my URL has `\` along with `/` as escape characters but i want to remove all the `\` from my URL because i want to use that URL in another service.

```
https:\/\/dev-api.cloudservicesplatform.biz:443\/CSPFileStore\/V1\/storefs\/32\/Fremont_300_355.png?appenduserid=0
```

this is the output im getting i want it to be like this:

```
https://dev-api.cloudservicesplatform.biz:443/CSPFileStore/V1/storefs/32/Fremont_300_355.png?appenduserid=0
```

MY regular Expression is `URL":"(.+?)"`
Kindly help, im new to Jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about replacing and removing characters using the REGEX extractor, but you could put a Post Processor (JSR 223, Beanshell, etc.) on the request and remove the offending \'s there.

```
def myVar = vars.get("myVar")
def url = myVar.replace("\\", "")
vars.put("url", url)
```

This code is meant for a JSR 223 Processor using Groovy as the selected language.

Beanshell code is as follows:

```
String myVar = vars.get("myVar")
String url = myVar.replace("\\", "")
vars.put("url", url)
```

Comment: Maybe, it should be `vars.put("myVar", url)`. In my case this worked as expected, not `vars.put("url", url)`. But, anyway, thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code and it's working fine.

Eariler I am getting "https:\//abcd.com\/testrail\/index.php?\/runs\/view\/14931"

Used the following BeanShell Listener with code:

```
try 
{

String TestRUNUrlNew;
bshVar=vars.get("TestRUNUrl"); 
bshVar=bshVar.replace("\\", "");   
vars.put("TestRUNUrlNew", bshVar);

}

catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Getting output like:
https://abcd.com/testrail/index.php?/runs/view/14931